# Writing $(41253)$ as the product of elementary transpositions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the question

> Write $\sigma$ as a product of elementary transpositions, where $\sigma = (4,1,2,5,3)$.

I know the answer, which is $s_3s_2s_1s_4$, but I don't understand how to calculate it. If someone could explain the procedure I would be really greatful. I saw this similar question: [Let σ = 42153, write σ as a product of elementary transpositions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1504779/let-%CF%83-42153-write-%CF%83-as-a-product-of-elementary-transpositions), but I don't understand that answer, so that's why I decided to ask myself.

Comment: So, what is it exactly that you dont understand? Is it the definition of "transposition" or "product of transposition"?

Comment: 'product of transposition' I guess. I don't understand how s3,s2 etc corresponds to the transpositions. @AndréPorto